# How to log out of iCloud on iPad?

Tags: ipad, icloud, login

I would like to log out of iCloud on iPad while staying logged into an Apple account.

Documentation for this is at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208242 and is wrong.

It states that I should sign out of my Apple account (done). Then I should login to my Apple account. This second step fails.

When attempting to login to my Apple account, after successfully entering a username, password, and two-factor authentication, the immediate next screen is this.

Please help explain how to login to an Apple account on iPad while logging out of the iCloud account.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "staying logged into an Apple account"? How are you differentiating 'iCloud' from 'Apple account'?

Comment: The documentation claims possible to logout of iCloud and "keep using the App Store" that's what I want. In general, Apple account is where you down apps, and iCloud is where Apple removes any semblance of privacy from your life.

Comment: So sign into the App Store app, not the iCloud settings page. Apple expects you to use one account for everything - for those of us who had iTunes accounts long before iCloud existed, that's how you keep them separated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments, but I'll spell it out here in more detail.

To sign out of iCloud but stay signed into iTunes, follow [the directions from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208242) (shown below). However, to sign back in to the App Store, note that the linked article is incorrect.

**Instead, go to the App Store settings page and sign in on this screen. This will prevent setting up iCloud in full.**

---

How to keep using the App Store, iMessage, and FaceTime on your device

When you sign out of iCloud, you're also automatically signed out of the App Store, iMessage, and FaceTime.

- To keep using the App Store, sign in with your Apple ID.
- To keep using iMessage and FaceTime, [use your phone number](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201349).

Comment: Perfect, thank you, "iCloud: off" achieved! Of course now I get the "start using iCloud" nag, which my only negative choice is "not now". How lovely of Apple to remind me who is in charge of our relationship.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken For most of those nags, if you click the notification instead of dismissing it it won't come back. Not sure about the iCloud one though.

Comment: That being said, you can enable iCloud and turn off all services to disable the nags. I don't know your exact situation but that's usually the best course.